# Insert array of objects to database

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have the following array containing objects, And there are arrays in the objects too.

```
let array = [
 {
  "data": {
    "Game": {
        "Game_number": [
            "4",
            "6",
            "8"
        ],
        "Game_name": [
            "Name_1",
            "Name_2",
            "name_3"
        ]
    },
    "AA": {
        "AA_count": [
            "30"
        ],
        "AA_name": [
            "Umbrella"
        ]
    },
  }
 }
]
```

Now i have to put them in database, Each have a column against.

But the issue is that the **above data is not constant**, So i cannot put them via their indexes. if the data is missing for a column than that's fine it will go empty

I tried via for each but that is inserting the last element of the array.

```
array.data.forEach((item) => {

    const Games = Parse.Object.extend('Games');
    const query = new Games();

    item.data.Game.Game_number.forEach((number) => {
        query.set('game_number', number);
    }, this);

    item.data.Game.Game_name.forEach((name) => {
        query.set('game_name', name);
    }, this);

    query.save();


}, this);
```

What will be a flexible way to handle it ?

Comment: *"I tried via for each but that is inserting the last element of the array."* - you should edit your post to show us what it was that you tried. Right now, you'd probably end up with too many possible answers and some may end up being incorrect.

Comment: is that an array of objects at the first place?

Comment: Share your code which inserts last value ? You said.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok, let me edit it.

Comment: @varun Yes.....

Comment: @user2486 ok let me share the code

Comment: @Fred-ii- Question Updated And i modified the array a bit please check

Comment: @varun Question Updated And i modified the array a bit please check

Comment: @user2486 Question Updated

Comment: where is your database?

Comment: @NinaScholz its hosted, And its Parse.com. Basically i can move the `Games` and `query` objects in the `foreach`, It will solve the issue for just one object inside object, Now the same table have other things too. I need to insert them also.

Comment: @NinaScholz One table have all the columns, And the columns data is stored above in the array of objects, Its not complete data but is the same like above.

Comment: What does `query.set('game_name', name);` do ?

Comment: @user2486 it loops through the array and gets the game, And i am setting the `game_name` to the value `name`.

Comment: @Gammer : and this the code which inserts last value right ?

Comment: @user2486 yes please see my comments to NinaScholz.

Comment: Are you overwritting the value instead adding like as `array` ?

Comment: @user2486 no i have to find a way out to put them into database in each row, If some values are missing for a row then those will go empty !